# Apache Proxy Access Configuration

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

My Ubuntu Server should manage the request for an WEB Cam IP Service.
My current config is:

- Ubuntu Server with Apache Web Server (192.168.1.210)
- Old Smart Phone with IP Cam APP (192.168.1.57) Service is running under Port 8081
- 192.168.1.57:8081/video should external accessible
- 192.168.1.57:8081/ should only internal (192.168.1.1/24) accessible

My current solution is:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests off
  ProxyPass /video http://192.168.1.57:8081/video
  ProxyPassReverse /video http://192.168.1.57:8081/video
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:8081>
<Proxy "*">
  Require ip 192.168.1
</Proxy>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests off
  ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.57:8081/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.57:8081/
</VirtualHost>
```

So i splitt internal and external with different port numbers.
How i can config the apache server to say: Forward all requests from 8080 to 192.168.1.57:8081/video but 192.168.1.57:8081/ is only for the local network?

Comment: How are you going to protect the actual source from getting requested directly, since it apparently is in the local network?

Comment: What is the motivation for splitting as you do? If the first host offers free access for all, then why should anyone use the second host?

Comment: @arkascha. 192.168.1.57 is behind the firewall. Only one portforwarding is active to the server to 8080. The motivation... /video is the video stream and the videostream should accesible from outside (internet). But / is the config page... and the config page should only available in the LAN.